# How to fully disable anti-aliasing in Gears of War 4 on PC?

Tags: pc, gears-of-war-4

Video settings only allow to set it to Low. Are there any config files that I can edit to fully disable anti-aliasing? Since it's Unreal Engine I assume there should be.

Comment: Why? According to https://segmentnext.com/2016/10/08/gears-of-war-4-tweaks-and-performance-guide/ and https://www.geforce.com/whats-new/guides/gears-of-war-4-graphics-and-performance-guide#gears-of-war-4-anti-aliasing-quality the anti-aliasing will not affect performance and you can safely put it on ultra.

Answer (score 1):

Gears of War 4 has configuration files that can be edited in the following directory:

*%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.SpartaUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\GearGame\Saved\Config\UWP*

There are some solutions for your problem offered in [this Steam thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/414340/discussions/0/1471967615867917385/):

- One of these files is *GameUserSettings.ini*, in which you can turn off anti-aliasing by changing the value of `sg.AntiAliasingQuality=` to `0`.

  Then, in another file called *Scalability.ini*, make sure that under `[AntiAliasingQuality@0]`, you have `r.PostProcessAAQuality=0`
- Another user [mentions](https://steamcommunity.com/app/414340/discussions/0/1471967615867917385/#c1471967615879211106) to only change *Scalability.ini*, and to edit in the following values:

  `[PostProcessQuality@3]
  r.MotionBlurQuality=0
  r.SceneColorFringeQuality=0
  r.PostProcessAAQuality=0`

Mentions of it ruining the visuals are abundant, though, so you probably need to do a lot of tweaking.

- Another option is to force AA off through [nVidia Settings](https://www.pcgamer.com/nvidia-control-panel-a-beginners-guide/) or [nVidia Inspector](https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/nvidia-inspector-download.html) if you have an nVidia GPU, or through [AMD Radeon Settings](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/dh-012) if you have Radeon GPU.

---

If the problem you have with Anti-Aliasing is the strain it puts on your eyes, or you just don't like it aesthetically, you might be interested in turning off Chromatic Aberration and Motion Blur as well, which can be done by editing the values as posted [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/414340/discussions/0/1471967615867917385/#c1471967615868027083).

As mentioned in that same post, be sure to change the properties of the edited files to 'Read-only'.

<sup>* I'm not sure about this, but the '*Microsoft.SpartaUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe*' folder might have a slightly different name. If anyone finds out, please post a comment and I'll edit it in.</sup>